# PHPMailer: Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client()

Tags: wordpress, phpmailer

I am getting the following error (using the WP Mail SMTP Plugin).

Any idea how to resolve this?

(All ports, passwords, etc are correct)

Thanks

```
Versions:
WordPress: 4.9.1
WordPress MS: No
PHP: 5.6.31-4+wpengine10
WP Mail SMTP: 1.2.2

Params:
Mailer: smtp
Constants: No
ErrorInfo: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Host: smtp.hosts.co.uk
Port: 465
SMTPSecure: ssl
SMTPAutoTLS: bool(false)
SMTPAuth: bool(true)

Server:
OpenSSL: Yes
SMTP Debug:
2018-01-15 15:54:32 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.hosts.co.uk:465, timeout=300, options=array ()
2018-01-15 15:54:39 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.hosts.co.uk:465 (Connection timed out)
2018-01-15 15:54:39 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
2018-01-15 15:54:39 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your ISP is blocking outbound SMTP. How to diagnose this is covered in [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) linked from the error message.

I can get to your host on that port, so it's definitely an issue with your network, not your code. You should ask your ISP or read their support docs about how they want you to send email.

Comment: Out of interest - if this is the case - would this apply to any visitor submitting a form. E.g. I can get my ISP to allow it but if Joe Bloggs in Timbuktu was browsing the site and his ISP blocks outbound SMTP then the email generated from his form submission would fail?

Comment: No, because the form is processed on *your* server, and the email is sent from there, not on the client's machine or browser.

Comment: Gotcha!! Thank you 